# How to show result of shuffle deck of blackjack card?

Tags: javascript, dom, blackjack

I'm making a simple blackjack game. Now, I make a card shuffle function. Why does the result of the card shake not appear in innerText after clicking the new game button?

I have reviewed and repeated the code and corrected the placement of variables and semicolon but it has no effect.

```js
/*
  Blackjack Game
*/

//Card Variables
let suits = ['Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades'],
  values = ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack',
    'Ten', 'Nine', 'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six',
    'Five', 'Four', 'Three', 'Two'
  ];

//DOM Variables
let textArea = document.getElementById('text-area'),
  newGameButton = document.getElementById('new-game-button'),
  hitButton = document.getElementById('hit-button'),
  stayButton = document.getElementById('stay-button');

//Game Variables
let gameStarted = false,
  gameOver = false,
  playerWon = false,
  dealerCard = [],
  playerCard = [],
  dealerScore = 0,
  playerScore = 0,
  deck = [];

hitButton.style.display = 'none';
stayButton.style.display = 'none';
showStatus();

newGameButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  gameStarted = true;
  gameOver = false;
  playerWon = false;

  deck = createDeck();
  shuffleDeck(deck);
  dealerCards = [getNextCard(), getNextCard()];
  playerCards = [getNextCard(), getNextCard()];

  newGameButton.style.display = 'none';
  hitButton.style.display = 'inline';
  stayButton.style.display = 'inline';
  showStatus();
});

function createDeck() { //Membuat deck dari 52 kartu
  let deck = [];
  for (let suitIdx = 0; suitIdx < suits.length; suitIdx++) {
    for (let valueIdx = 0; valueIdx < values.length; valueIdx++) {
      let card = {
        suit: suits[suitIdx],
        value: values[valueIdx]
      }
      deck.push(card);
    }
  }
  return deck;
}

function shuffleDeck(deck) {
  for (let i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
    let swapIdx = Math.trunc(Math.random() * deck.length);
    let tmp = deck[swapIdx];
    deck[swapIdx] = deck[i];
    deck[i] = tmp;
  }
}

function getCardString(card) {
  return card.value + ' of ' + card.suit;
}

function getNextCard() {
  return deck.shift();
}

function showStatus() {
  if (!gameStarted) {
    textArea.innerText = 'Welcome to Blackjack!';
    return;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
  textArea.innerText = "\n" + getCardString(deck[i]);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Welcome to Blackjack!</h1>
<h4>by Andrean Hendy</h4>

<p id="text-area">Welcome to Blackjack!</p>
<button id="new-game-button">New Game!</button>
<button id="hit-button">Hit!</button>
<button id="stay-button">Stay</button>
```

Check the code here@plunk: http://embed.plnkr.co/rAzcbmTyH8vIRBI3appX/

What i expected is to show the result of 52 deck card after shuffling.

Comment: I see that you assign two cards to the player and the dealer, but I don't see where you put them on hte screen? Your last `for` loop only runs once (when the page loads), at which point you haven't created the `deck` yet.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {` at the bottom doesn't look like it will run. It looks like it's executed before `deck` is populated, so there's nothing to loop over.

Answer (score 0):

In your "new-game-button" button click event listener you never change your "text-area" innerText. The only sub-method that could do it is `showStatus`, but `if(!gameStarted)` condition protects us from innerText changing in this case.

Not sure if I understood your logic properly, but following update will show you the result after clicking on "New game" button.

```
newGameButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // ...
  setDeckText();
});

// ...

function setDeckText() {
  for(var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++){
    textArea.innerText = "\n" + getCardString(deck[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for the answer, here is the problem, when button newgame clicked i want to display getCardString to screen, which card has been shuffled

Answer (score 0):

the problem is finished. looping on the last lines should be placed in the showStatus() function block.but I didn't before.